# Best Crown Capper

Tags: equipment, bottling, capping

Just capped my first batch of beer (Wohoo!).

When I invested in my equipment though, I think I was a bit too frugal with my capping tool - I have a hammer on crown capper. It seems to have done the job (hard to tell at this stage if the seals are good, but they seem OK), but it was pretty hard work capping 64 x 330ml bottles with it...

What recommendations can anyone out there in homebrewland make for a better capper (considering value for money) - 2 handled capper (mid-range cost)? Bench capper (high-end cost)... or should I just persevere with the hammer on capper (cheap-as-chips)?

Any suggestions appreciated...

Cheers,
Perk.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... I'm not hearing anyone say that a hammer on capper is the under-appreciated capping solution.
So, it's time for an upgrade - based on my limited budget and storage space, I'm going to go for a two-handled capper. Once day, when I win the lottery and have a dedicated brewing shed I'll invest in a bench capper!
Cheers.

Comment: FYI, you can leave this sort of commentary as a comment on your question, rather than as it's own answer.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering how I was s'posed to do that. Thanks... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 handle capper is what i've been using for years.  It works just fine, I haven't had any problems with it.  It's very cheap and less annoying than the hammer on capper.  I will eventually move to the bench capper, but my brew equipment is taking up enough space as it is.  I would definitely recommend the jump to the 2 handle capper.

Comment: I ended up borrowing a two handled capper, and this worked perfectly - quick, easy and forms a reliable seal. I would recommend any new brewer _to not even bother with a hammer on capper_ - just get a 2 handled capper to start. But, I have since purchased a bench capper - if you have the space and the budget, this is definitely the way to go. It makes the process **way** faster. The bench capper also has no problem with the bottles tending to tip over, which is the only downside of the two handled capper.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer the bench capper. It's a little more expensive, but I think it works better / faster / easier. I broke my first one recently, after using it for over 5 years.

Comment: I definitely agree, I just need the space.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that if you get a bench capper that its not made of plastic. i bought a bench capper from a home brew store, thinking i was spending money wisely. i found out after bottling my first batch today that it was junk. the bottles tend to lean to one side because the plastic parts flexed to much.